# Erro DataSnap com Indy

Tags: delphi

Fiz uma aplicação servidora que chamando os métodos pelo *browse*, funciona tudo perfeito, mas pra testar meus métodos construí um cliente usando `TdHTTP` o e chamo os métodos da seguinte forma:

```
procedure TF_CLIENTE.SBEnviar2Click(Sender: TObject);
var Url        : String;
    lJSO       : String;
    jsonToSend : TStringStream;
begin

  Url := 'http://localhost:809...ecomandoPOST/';

  lJSO                                    := ('{"name":"TESTE"}');
  jsonToSend                              := TStringStream.Create(lJSO,TEncoding.UTF8);

  idHttp.ProxyParams.Clear;
  idHttp.ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication  := false;
  idHttp.Request.BasicAuthentication      := True;
  idHttp.Request.Accept                   := 'text/javascript';
  IdHTTP.Request.ContentType              := 'application/json';
  IdHTTP.Request.ContentEncoding          := 'utf-8';
  idHttp.Request.Method                   := 'POST';
  IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication      := True;
  IdHTTP.Request.Authentication           := TIdBasicAuthentication.Create;
  IdHttp.Request.Authentication.Username  := 'USUARIO';
  IdHttp.Request.Authentication.password  := 'SENHA';
  IdHttp.Request.ContentLength            := Length(lJSO);
  try
    Memo1.Text := idHttp.Post(Url,jsonToSend);
  except
    on E : Exception do
      begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Exception class name = '+E.ClassName);
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Exception message = '+E.Message);
      end;
  end;

end;
```

Já Liberei o `Dispatch`:

```
procedure TF_WebModule.WebModuleBeforeDispatch(Sender: TObject;
  Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Response.SetCustomHeader('access-control-allow-origin','*');
  Response.SetCustomHeader('access-control-allow-Methods','PUT, POST, GET, DELETE');
  Response.SetCustomHeader('access-control-allow-Headers','accept, authorization, origin');
  if FServerFunctionInvokerAction <> nil then
  FServerFunctionInvokerAction.Enabled := AllowServerFunctionInvoker;
end;
```

Já validei o usuário e vem a autenticação certinho do Indy:

```
procedure TF_WebModule.DSAuthenticationManager1UserAuthenticate(Sender: TObject;
  const Protocol, Context, User, Password: string; var valid: Boolean;
  UserRoles: TStrings);
begin

  if Request.Method = 'OPTIONS' then
    valid := False
  else
    if ((User = 'USUARIO') and (Password = 'SENHA')) then
      valid := True
    else
      valid := False;

end;
```

Ele apresenta um erro:

> Exception class name = EIdHTTPProtocolException Exception message =
>   HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Olá Aparecido, o erro HTTP 500 indica que ocorreu um erro no servidor. Se você estiver debugando o servidor não ocorre nenhuma exceção?

Comment: Há uma regra para a formação a URI segue o link q deve ser a base: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/DataSnap_REST

Answer (score -1):

essa url está errada

Url := 'http://localhost:809...ecomandoPOST/';

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele - você sempre pode comentar em suas próprias publicações e quando tiver [pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes você poderá [comentar sobre qualquer publicação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: A causa do erro pode ser a própria URL, @rray.